# Meteor + React + createcontainer

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, meteor-accounts

Using react with meteor here, I have main component called App, and it wraps page layout (Header, Sidebar, Right-sidebar).

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navigation">
          <Header />
          <Sidebar />
        </nav>
        <div className="content">
          <Subnavbar />
          <div className="container">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
        <Rightsidebar />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I'm trying to setup authentication system using Meteor's built in auth system. using "*accounts-password*" package.

To my knowldge, I need to use *createContainer* from 'meteor/react-meteor-data' to inject auth params to components.

Similar to this example:

```
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import MainPage from '../pages/MainPage.jsx'
export default MainContainer = createContainer(({params}) => {
  const currentUser = Meteor.user();
  return {
    currentUser,
  };
}, MainPage);
```

However in the above example, it only injects the parms to a single component, how can I go about injecting auth info to all components in my app (Header, Sidebars ..etc)

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap `App` in `createContainer`, then `App` will have a prop `currentUser`. It can then be the responsibility of `App` to pass the `currentUser` prop to all of your components. If you find yourself passing around `currentUser` far too much, then you can wrap only the components that need `currentUser` in `createContainer`.

In that case you would have `HeaderContainer`, `SidebarContainer`, etc, each being wrapped with `createContainer`.

Comment: I ended up creating `HeaderContainer` as per your answer and it works, thanks for your help :)